# How to Get Label Text Value in Page Markup?

Tags: asp.net

Hello
I need to get a label's text value to use in an `<a>` tag's link.
I tried to use it like `<a href="Page.aspx?l=<%=Label.Text%>" runat="server">` and similar usages I know and it didn't help.
Any ways to make that work?

Comment: I might not be very imaginative, but I can't figure out a reasonable scenario where you'd do this.

Comment: I'm trying to build a multilanguage page and the link I give is undercontrolled by css and jquery so I can't make it codebehind. Though, I found a way and did it in codebehind but the page didn't work correctly in Google Chrome, something wrong with session variables. So I decided to put a label. (old and useless trick but last option)

Comment: undercontrolled? Can't imagine what the browser choice has to do with session variables...

Comment: Just to make it clear, that's the exact problem I faced with and couldn't solve... http://forums.asp.net/t/1552666.aspx/1?Session+variable+value+lost+in+Chrome+but+works+fine+in+IE+amp+FF+

Comment: I think what you should do to answer that question is to detail out the differences in the requests by the browser. Obviously you'll get a different value for the user agent server variable, but I'm guessing most of the other values in the request will be exactly the same. If you find some difference between the requests, then you'll find your problem. Check the header, form and query strings. You can do this using Response.Write in the Global.asax BeginRequest, or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look what you said. May I contact if I can't figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you're making the anchor control a server side control, which is making it not allow the markup inside it.

```
<a href="Page.aspx?l=<%=Label.Text%>">My Anchor</a>
```

Should work, but please rethink your design.